# Gradle Error in Android Studio upon first installing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently began using Android Studio and was trying to follow the "First App" tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/). When I create a new project in Android Studio, however, I am almost immediately greeted by this error

```
ERROR: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip'.
```

I've tried deleting my ~/.gradle directory and invalidating caches before restarting android studio but this doesn't fix the issue. I've also tried downloading gradle and using a local distribution of it, as well as playing with the version both locally and the default gradle wrapper version found in the cradle-wrapper.properties file. I tried both using the most current distribution (6.0.1) as well as going back a few versions and nothing has helped.

I am running on Mac OS 10.13.6 and Android Studio 3.5.2, using a Nougat distribution for my project (API 24, Android 7.0).

Edit: When I open the event logger, this is what I see:

```
11:18   Gradle sync started with single-variant sync

11:18   Gradle sync failed: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger (2 s 7 ms)

11:18   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

Edit:

build.gradle files

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eecs285.proj4.nortoncofirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you add both Gradle files here

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. You can add the code by editing your post

Comment: Noted, code added above. Sorry about that.

Comment: No, I haven't even started on the project I want to work on. This error occurred immediately after starting a new project in Android Studio

Comment: have you installed java in your system? if so then what is the version of the java that is installed?

Comment: I have the most recent version of the jdk installed (13.0.1) and the jre (java 8 update 231)